# Why im getting an undefined as result with first "onSubmit" but second is ok

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

Why when I call the "handle Search" function for the first time I get "undefined" but the second time I get my result.

```
    const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?';
    const location = `location=${latitude},${longitude}`;
    const radius = '&radius=2000';
    const type = '&keyword=restaurant';
    const key = '&key=xxxxxxxx';
    const SearchUrl = proxy + url + location + radius + type + key;
    console.log(SearchUrl);
    fetch(SearchUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
        SetList({list: result})
    })
    console.log(list);
}
```

EDIT: Shouldn't it be alright now? Still undefined for the first time

```
    const handleSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?';
    const location = `location=${latitude},${longitude}`;
    const radius = '&radius=2000';
    const type = '&keyword=restaurant';
    const key = '&key=xxxxxxx';
    const SearchUrl = proxy + url + location + radius + type + key;
    SetList({list: await myRespone(SearchUrl)})
    console.log(list);
}

function myRespone(SearchUrl) {
    console.log(SearchUrl);
    fetch(SearchUrl).then(response => response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{return responseJson});
}
```

Comment: show the `SetList` function code, did you using setState or hooks?

Comment: const [list, SetList] = useState();

Answer (score 0):

"Fetch" is an asynchronous function. When you console "list", the request has not been completed. So you can't get it. The second time there is a value because, after the first request is completed, the value is assigned to the list.

--- edit after---

Yours is obviously wrong. You need to understand, "async， await， Promise", the relationship between asynchronous and synchronous, your problem can be solved very well. Come on.

Example：

```
SetList({list: await myRespone(SearchUrl)})

function async myRespone(SearchUrl) {
 try {
   console.log(SearchUrl);
   let res = await fetch(SearchUrl);
   return res.json()
 }catch(err) {console.error(err)}
}
```

Comment: Please see my newly edited. Hope to give you ideas

Answer (score 0):

Put console.log(list) outside handleSearch to get the latest value

```
const handleSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?';
    const location = `location=${latitude},${longitude}`;
    const radius = '&radius=2000';
    const type = '&keyword=restaurant';
    const key = '&key=xxxxxxx';
    const SearchUrl = proxy + url + location + radius + type + key;
    SetList({list: await myRespone(SearchUrl)})
    
}
console.log(list);
```

The update value of useState is asynchronous, you cannot get the latest value synchronously. Only after the hooks update the value, the component re-render can get the updated value

Answer (score 0):

I would convert this to an async function to make it a bit easier to read. You can use a `useEffect` to console log every time the value of `list` changes to see when exactly that happens.

```js
    const handleSearch = async (e) => { 

      e.preventDefault();
      const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
      const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?';
      const location = `location=${latitude},${longitude}`;
      const radius = '&radius=2000';
      const type = '&keyword=restaurant';
      const key = '&key=xxxxxxxx';
      const SearchUrl = proxy + url + location + radius + type + key;
      console.log(SearchUrl);

      const response = await fetch(SearchUrl)
      const result = await response.json()
      console.log(result);

      SetList({list: result})
}

useEffect(()=>{
console.log("the value of list changed!", list)
},[list)
```